# Prevent multiple sort parameters with Pageable in Spring REST Controllers

Tags: java, spring, sorting, spring-data, spring-restcontroller

I'm working an API using Spring Boot and Spring Data repos (although not Spring Data REST).

```
@GetMapping
public List<Foo> listFoos(
    @SortDefault(value = "name", direction = Sort.Direction.ASC)
    Pageable pageable,
    HttpServletRequest request) {
  FooRepo.findAll(pageable);
}
```

The above works fine. I can sort fine by passing a `sort` parameter, however I'm a bit concerned about the performance implications.

I'd like to limit it to only support sort by a single parameter at a time for performance reasons. By default, I can do something like `?sort=name,createdAt` which will generate a query to order by both `name` and `createdAt`. Given it's a public API, I'm a bit concerned about some users abusing this and attempting to sort by a whole bunch of values that we haven't optimised for.

Secondly, there are some values that don't make sense for sorting. For example, if `Foo` had a thumbnail URL, it wouldn't make sense to sort by `thumbnail`. Is there any ability to whitelist or blacklist the sort values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make your `CustomSortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` ( implements `org.springframework.data.web.SortArgumentResolver` 
spring implementation `org.springframework.data.web.SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        PageableArgumentResolverhandler = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver(
                new CustomSortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver()); 

        argumentResolvers.add(handler);
    } 
}
```

in custom implementation, you can create white/black lists and customize the processing of the collation so as to you conveniently, and to avoid common mistakes - see the implementation of the spring

one of the ways

```
public class CustomSortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver extends 
        SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver{



    @Override
    public Sort resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) {
        Sort sort = super.resolveArgument(parameter, mavContainer, webRequest, binderFactory);

        /*
            additional logic for filtering orders        
         */

        return sort != null && sort.iterator().hasNext() ? new Sort(sort.iterator().next()) : null;
    }
}
```